# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"

Tags: activerecord, syntax-error

I am wondering if anyone can explain why I get this error in ActiveRecord SQL injection, but tests pass when I add `.to_a`?  I am using PostgreSQL with Ruby on Rails and RSpec.

```rb
def top_5_authors
  books.joins(review: :author)
    .where('books.title = ?', 'reviewed')
    .select("CONCAT(authors.first_name,' ', authors.last_name) AS full_name, COUNT(books.id) AS         book_count")
    .group('full_name')
    .order('book_count DESC')
    .limit(5)
    # .to_a
end
```

This is the error message when I comment out `.to_a`:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
     PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
     LINE 1: ...AT(authors.first_name,' ', authors.last_name) AS full_na...
                                                                    ^
```

It seems that returning the query as an array overwrites the syntax error, possibly having something to do with the SQL injection at `.select` where I am using `CONCAT`.  However I've tried multiple combinations without `CONCAT` and without the alias `full_name` and it then throws an error at `AS book_count`.  I've tried it without that alias as well and refactored accordingly.

In both situations, when I add `.to_a` it works fine.

I believe I'm querying with correct syntax, could be wrong as both SQL and ActiveRecord are new to me, but when using `.to_a` it works fine and I can access the data I need.  I'm just failing to understand why at the moment.  Any ideas would be welcome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your statement that your tests pass when you use `.to_a`, that would suggest that your test is chaining another method onto `top_5_authors` like `.count`.  You can safely call `.count` on an Array.  But you can't always call `.count` on an ActiveRecord relation depending on the SQL aggregations you are performing.

If you try to run your test and then you look at what is in `log/test.log` you should be able to see the full SQL query it was trying to run.  If you were using `.count` in your test it might have something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(CONCAT(authors.first_name,' ', authors.last_name) AS full_name, COUNT(books.id) AS book_count) AS ...
```

In this case, ActiveRecord wrapped the `select` value within a `COUNT` function.  Using a column alias within `COUNT` isn't allowed.

I would suggest going into the Rails console and seeing how ActiveRecord behaves for these simpler queries to get a feel for what is going on:

```rb
# This will count all books
Book.count

# This will count all books with non-null titles
Book.select('title').count

# This will crash on a StatementInvalid error because you can't 
# alias a column within a count
Book.select('title AS x').count

# This will load all books into an array and then compute the array length
Book.select('title AS x').to_a.count
```